# Running python script to get SQL Statement for Google BigQuery

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

Trying to run a script that contains a SQL query:

```
import example_script
example_script.df.describe()
example_script.df.info()

q1 = '''
example_script.df['specific_column'])
'''
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
query_job = client.query(q1, job_config= job_config)
q = query_job.to_dataframe()
```

Issues I'm having are when I import it, how do I get that specific column name used as a text? Then it will run the query from GBQ but instead, it's stuck in pandas formatting that Google doesn't want to read. Are there other options?

Comment: It is not clear what is inside `example_script.df['specific_column'])`. If you are sending a query, at least there is a table being queried. What is the name of your table?

Comment: Sorry. The 'specific_column' is the updated SQL query with multiple tables being queried.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but I think you have a sql query inside `example_script.df['specific_column'])` and you want it to insert it in q1. Have you tried using ` ''' {} '''.format(example_script.df['specific_column']))` ? Other option would be using `example_script.df.loc['specific_column', <INDEX>]` since without the loc that should be a column

Comment: Thanks yeah it has a sql statement, I updated the question. is there a way to find the index?